# How to arrange this in table format

Tags: php, html

How do I arrange this in table format? I am unable to arrange this in table format

```
<?php 
include("database.php");

$fileStorage = '../upload/'; 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM upload ORDER By no DESC limit 10") or die(mysql_error()); 

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>echo $row['no'];</td>
   <td> echo $row['title'];</td>
        <td>echo '<a href="'. $fileStorage . $row['file'] .'" target="_blank">'. htmlentities('Click Here', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') .'</a><br />';</td></tr></table>
    } 
}
?>
```

Comment: As in HTML tables? If so, this is [**HTML 101**](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/html-one-o-one)

Comment: You need to format it as a table. Add <table> and row <tr> and column <td> tags.

Comment: while i am adding its coming as unexpected '<'

Comment: You need to post the code that you tried, not the code that you want us to write for you; that's not how things go on Stack. You're most probably injecting HTML into PHP, that's why you're getting the error of unexpected `<`

Comment: My above comment says just that ^^^^^ - You can't just inject HTML code like that into PHP, you have to [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace Your cycle with this piece of code:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo "<table>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['no'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
        echo '<td><a href="' . $fileStorage . $row['file'] . '" target="_blank">' . htmlentities('Click Here', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . '</a></td>';
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: while adding border to table its showing as unexpected '1'

Comment: What do you mean? you probably didnt escape the quotes. Try to put them in single quotes, or escape them. with a backslash.

Comment: Did this solve your issue? If it did, then please accept the answer. There are so many answers in stackoverflow which havent been accepted, but have solved the issue.